# Windows 10 boot fails with 0x82f after update

Tags: windows-10, boot, motherboard, machine-check-exception

After last nights update my Windows machine (hpe-420cs) entered into infamous boot loop, reporting MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION as the cause.

I tried to roll back the update in boot menu, with process immidiately failing, system recovery also failed for all available recovery points, startup repair also failed, several times.

Eventually I got into safe mode, after several failed attempts and without networking.

Upon inspecting srttrail.txt I found only one error code: 0x82f.
Apart from that all tests came clean.

As far as I know the machine itself is ok and for the last year there were no hardware changes, up to and including overclocking or any changes in BIOS or drivers.

I have run several test, both integrated and external, memory, HDD, power supply are all without issues. I couldn't check integrated network card but it does seem to work judging by blinking lights around ethernet port and packets received by my router. USB does seem to work as well, mouse and keyboard worked fine in the recovery mode and the safe mode, I could also download files on flashdrive withou issue.

The bootrec command identified a possible issue, while the recovery partition is ok it couldn't find the windows installation itself. I have deleted old bcd and rebuild it successfully.

Unfortunately boot failed again.

If this situation is anything like the last 5 times I got this exception then I can, if there is no other way, simply reinstall windows from recovery partition.
But I would prefer to avoid that since it means spending next two days setting up my toolchain.

Also I can't update BIOS or drivers since manufacturer no longer provides updates.

Comment: Can you specific the update?

Comment: Version 1703, build 15063.

Comment: I think you mean 15063.608